# Getting RGBA value of PNG imgae in sdl2

Tags: c++11, sdl-2

I need RGBA value of image for generating height of my terrain and I'm using sdl for load image I looked around and found `SDL_GetRGBA` should return those value but every time I run this code my program crash...

```
SDL_Surface *image = IMG_Load(HightMapAddress);
SDL_LockSurface(image);
Uint32 *pixels = (Uint32 *)image->pixels;
Uint8* RED;
Uint8* GREEN;
Uint8* BLUE;
Uint8* ALPHA;
SDL_GetRGBA(pixels[0], image->format, RED, GREEN, BLUE, ALPHA);
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 1):

`SDL_GetRGBA` gets pointers to memory where it should write resulting colours. You passed uninitialised pointers, so said function will attempt to write to unknown location. Luckly it will crash, otherwise you'll stomp some random location in memory.

Correct code would be something like

```
Uint8 RED;
Uint8 GREEN;
Uint8 BLUE;
Uint8 ALPHA;
SDL_GetRGBA(pixels[0], image->format, &RED, &GREEN, &BLUE, &ALPHA);
```